# P5 in Nextjs 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I copied this code from the documentation of [react-p5-next-wrapper](https://github.com/P5-wrapper/next).

```
"use client"; 

import React from "react";
import { type Sketch } from "@p5-wrapper/react";
import { NextReactP5Wrapper } from "@p5-wrapper/next";

const sketch: Sketch = (p5) => {
  p5.setup = () => p5.createCanvas(600, 400, p5.WEBGL);

  p5.draw = () => {
    p5.background(250);
    p5.normalMaterial();
    p5.push();
    p5.rotateZ(p5.frameCount * 0.01);
    p5.rotateX(p5.frameCount * 0.01);
    p5.rotateY(p5.frameCount * 0.01);
    p5.plane(100);
    p5.pop();
  };
};

export default function Page() {
  return <NextReactP5Wrapper sketch={sketch} />;
}
```

I receive this error:

```
./node_modules/@p5-wrapper/react/dist/component/react.js
Module parse failed: Identifier 'je' has already been declared (7762:41)
|                                 if (F ? k || ($ = !0, A(), k = !0) : $ = !!je.first, H = Math.max(0, Math.floor(H)), Q = Math.max(0, Math.floor(Q)), $) {
|                                     if (!re) throw new Error("First frame must include a { palette } option");
>                                     var [je, we, fe, De, he = 8] = [
|                                         G,
|                                         H,
```

Please help me to figure out what was wrong. By the way, can you show me the way to use p5 in Nextjs?

I even tried this code:

```
import React from "react";
import { setup, draw } from "./sketch";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Sketch = dynamic(import("react-p5"), {ssr: false});

interface SketchComponentProps {}

const SketchComponent: React.FC<SketchComponentProps> = () => {
  return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
};

export default SketchComponent;
```

But it didnt work neither.